# What is wrong with my Systemd service file?

Tags: scripts, startup, systemd, gnu-screen

I've been trying to get a systemd service to work for a while now, but with no luck. What I am trying to do is create a startup script that will start a java program for a modded-Minecraft server.

Here is the systemd service file named `ftbstart.service`. It is placed in `/etc/systemd/system/` and has permissions 744 (though I tested a variety of different permissions).

```
[Unit]
Description=FTB Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
Group=root
RemainAfterExit=yes

ExecStart=/usr/games/ftb/sstart.sh
ExecStop=/usr/games/ftb/sstop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So ExecStart starts another script with permissions 755 called 
`sstart.sh` which contains the lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo I made it to 1
mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024M tmpfs /usr/games/ftb/current/
echo I made it to 2
cp -r /usr/games/ftb/beyond/. /usr/games/ftb/current/
echo I made it to 3
/usr/bin/screen -S ftb -d -m /usr/games/ftb/current/ServerStart.sh
echo I made it to 4
```

The echos are there for debugging purposes. The script runs all the way through, as

```
journalctl -u ftbstart
```

shows all echos from 1-4, however screen -list doesn't show any active screens after

```
systemctl restart ftbstart
```

However if I execute the script `/usr/games/ftb/sstart.sh` from the `/bin/bash` command line it runs perfectly fine and starts up no problem.

Things I've tried so far:

- adding `#!/bin/bash` to top of `ftbstart.service` file
- removing `After=`
- changing/removing `Type=` (`Type=simple` and `Type=forking`)
- changing/removing `User=` and `Group=`
- changing file permissions on both `ftbstart.service` and `sstart.sh`
- putting `ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/games/ftb/sstart.sh`

I also make sure to type:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and

```
systemctl restart ftbstart
```

each time I test something in the `ftbstart.service` file, etc etc and nothing seems to work.

I have also tried just adding the line

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -S ftb -d -m /usr/games/ftb/current/ServerStart.sh
```

to ftbstart.service but it still doesn't execute the screen service, but

```
systemctl status ftbstart
```

just shows something like:

```
Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-09-07 20:56:35 UTC; 32min ago
```

However if I replace that `ExecStart=` in `ftbstart.service` with one such as:

```
ExecStart=screen -S top -d -m /usr/bin/top
```

then it DOES WORK magically! It creates a screen which can be attached to and shows the top command-line resource monitor.

So, sorry for the long question, but can anybody help me figure out what I am doing wrong? My guess is that because I am starting another script rather than a program that something is messing up somewhere, but I am not sure. Thank you for any assistance you may provide.

P.S. If it is necessary, here is the startup script that is started by `sstart.sh`. I did not create this, it is the provided script that came with the minecraft modpack: https://pastebin.com/muCy0xnh

Comment: Why are you copying files to a tmpfs?  And screen is an interactive program that requires a terminal; you can't run it from systemd.

Comment: @psusi I am copying files to a tmpfs for the purpose of running the Minecraft world from a ramdisk, which is just a bit faster than running it directly from the HDD. Thank you for this response, I haven't found any information suggesting this in all my googling. Mind if I private message you to ask you for more information? I don't want to go off-topic in the post by asking more questions.

Comment: Also, @psusi I have used a Systemd service file with ExecStart=screen -S top -d -m /usr/bin/top and have successfully run screen from Systemd, so I am not sure why you say it can't be done.

Comment: Have you enabled the service (`sudo systemctl enable ftbstart.service`)? Beyond that, I would recommend that you break your issue into smaller, more discrete pieces that will make troubleshooting much easier.

Comment: The first thing to do is add `2>/tmp/foo.log` after each of the commands run by your script and then check `/tmp/foo.log` for any error messages. Your echo statements don't tell you anything about whether the commands were run successfully.